# Objective-C++ and Swift - nested structs in bridging header

Tags: swift, objective-c++, bridging-header

Please help me with the following issue. I am using the swift argument parser library https://github.com/apple/swift-argument-parser

Suppose I have this swift code in some swift file:

```swift
@objc public class Math: NSObject, ParsableCommand {
    static var configuration = CommandConfiguration(
        abstract: "A utility for performing maths.",
        subcommands: [Add.self],
        defaultSubcommand: Add.self)
}
    
extension Math {
    struct Add: ParsableCommand {
        static var configuration = CommandConfiguration(abstract: "Print the sum of the values.")        
        mutating func run() {
            print("0")
        }
    }
}
```

` and I want to call to an objective-c++ function named "func" with an argument which is of type Math.Add like so from main.swift file:

```swift
var status: Int32 = 0
do {
    // try to parse application arguments
    var args = try Math.parseAsRoot()
    switch args {
        case let args as Math.Add:
            status = func(args)
        default:
            try args.run()
        }
} catch {
    //Some code...
}
```

What should be the signature of the function and how the bridging-header files should look like? I made the signature be:

```
extern "C" int func(Math.Add *args);
```

And my bridging header is like so:

```
#ifndef __BRIDGING_HEADER_H__
#define __BRIDGING_HEADER_H__



@class Math;


#ifdef __cplusplus
   extern "C" {
#endif
   int func(Math.Add  *args);
#ifdef __cplusplus
    }
#endif

#endif /* __BRIDGING_HEADER_H__ */
```

but is doesn't work and the bridging header doesn't compile (Xcode writes the error: Interface type 'Math' cannot be passed by value; did you forget * in 'Math'?

Answer (score 2):

Objective-C(++) doesn't support nested types, what you can do if you want to keep the nested structure on Swift, is to export a non-nested type for Objective-C:

```swift
extension Math {
    @objc(Math_Add) // or MathAdd, or whatever name you like
    struct Add: ParsableCommand {
```

, which can then be referenced in your header:

```cpp
int func(Math_Add  *args);
```

As a side note, I would also change the name of the `func` function to something that doesn't collide with Swift keywords. Even if you'll be able to call it, it will be confusing for other readers of your code.